Instaloader выдает неверную информацию о публикациях
В своем скрипте я анализирую информацию через Instaloader, но данные отображаются устаревшими, например, скрипт показывает 1080 просмотров, а на видео 3000, в чем может быть дело?
posts = []
for post in profile.get_posts():
    if post.is_video and post.video_view_count is not None:
        posts.append(post)

filtered_posts = filter_videos(posts, min_engagement, max_engagement)

all_stats = []
for post in filtered_posts:
    try:
        L.download_post(post, target=profile_folder)
        engagement = calculate_engagement(post.likes, post.comments, post.video_view_count)
        post_url = f"https://www.instagram.com/p/{post.shortcode}/"

        stats = {
            "Url": post_url,
            "Views": post.video_view_count,
            "Engagement": engagement,
            "Likes": post.likes,
            "Comments": post.comments,
            "Filename": video_file_name
        }
        all_stats.append(stats)
    except Exception as download_e:
        print(f"An Exception has occurred during the download: {download_e}")

df = pd.DataFrame(all_stats)
stats_filename = os.path.join(profile_folder, f"{profile_name}_stats.xlsx")
df.to_excel(stats_filename, index=False)

